# multiple calls to jQuery.globalEval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following generic Ajax response writer which I recently added some logic to, in order to dynamically parse the results for script objects, and run them when I find them using `jQuery.globalEval()`.

Here is the code:

```
//Generic Results Writter method for Ajax Calls
function writeAjaxResponse(targetId, response) {

   document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = response;

   try {
        var dom = $j(response);

        dom.find('script').each( function(){ 
            $j.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
        });

   } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error parsing for script reloads: "+e);
   }

}
```

This solution works very nicely the first time its called. However `writeAjaxResponse(targetId, response);` is called each time a user loads some dynamic Ajax content. And unfortunately after the first time, the scripts are no longer loaded. To be clear, after the server side generated page is loaded, there are numerous links on the page which the users may click, which invoke this handler for the Ajax response.

No error occurs, and no `console.error()` is written.. The Ajax data loads as normal, its just that the scripts in the response are no longer loaded.

In debugging, `$j.globalEval` is still getting called and `this.text` still has the script content in it, and the data looks correct, but still no joy.

Any light someone could shed on this would be very much appreciated!

Adding main ajax call for GET for reference:

```
function doAjaxGet(targetId, getUrl, handler) {`
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
       // code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           try {
               handler(targetId, xmlhttp.response);
           }
           catch (err) {
               alert("Failed calling handler, detail: " + err + " Got     responseText: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
           }
       }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET", getUrl, true);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Also not sure if this helps, but are you able to try using `$.ajax`'s `dataType` option of `script` that will also execute code in the global context? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: cyber_dave I am using jQuery `v1.12.4`. And no, I have not tried changing my ajax setup yet, but may if that is recommended.. Currently this is the main ajax call handler I use. I have both POST and GET versions, but I added the the GET version to the main question for reference.